# Does Javascript have functions for use instead of binary operators?

Tags: javascript, function, logical-operators, binary-operators

My question is best illustrated with an example.

Is there a way to use syntax like

```
array.reduce(and)
```

instead of

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a && b)
```

in Javascript?

Similar questions hold for other binary operators, such as `|| + - *` and many, many others. A similar question exists for the `!` operator, e.g., `array.map(not)`.

**EDIT:**

Apologies, if not clear enough. I meant to ask whether JS has actual *built-in* aliases for the mentioned operators, like some other languages. I'm well aware that I can define my own functions to do this.

Comment: in short: no, but you could just use an own function.

Comment: => is not a binary operator , it a return

Comment: No, it does not.  But it's easy to write them in ES6.  Some libraries include them too.

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif: The operator in question here is the `&&` operator, not the arrow.

Comment: @NinaScholz if that's the common knowledge, please post a definitive no as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect, yes — they're called *functions*. :-)

```js
const and = (a, b) => a && b;
let array = [true, false, true];
console.log(array.reduce(and)); // false
array = [true, true, true];
console.log(array.reduce(and)); // true
```

I've used an arrow function there, but it could be any kind of function.

JavaScript doesn't have any *other* way of doing that, but functions do the job nicely, providing reusable semantics for common operations.

#### Re your edit

> I meant to ask whether JS has actual built-in aliases for the mentioned operators, like some other languages.

No — but the code you showed wouldn't be using an alias anyway. An alias would have looked like this: `array.reduce((a, b) => a and b)`

Comment: thank you, I was aware of that. I was wondering, if there are built-ins. E.g. in Mathematica `a && b` is shorthand for `And[a, b]` which is a built-in function.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: Gotcha. No. A couple of predefined functions are sometimes useful for a subset of operations, but mostly for coercion (for instance, `Boolean` for converting truthy values to `true` and falsy values to `false` -- `[0, 1, 2].map(Boolean)` is `[false, true, true]`).

Comment: For my general education, do you know of the correct term for the thing I'm looking for? Alias is, apparently, the wrong word.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: I don't know if there is a *general purpose* one. I'll ping someone I know who may know... I don't think "alias" is a million miles off, it's just such a broad term that it passed people by. But note how in Mathematic the expression is rewritten as well, so not *just* an alias. Hmmm.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: He said "alias" or perhaps "macro". The latter fits the way the thing is rewritten.

Comment: For myself I found this C++ reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/ which names this "additional function object class". Oh, well...

Comment: I figured your answer came closest, so green tick for you :)

Answer (score 2):

The only binary operators that have builtin function equivalents are `**` ([`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)) and `in` ([`Reflect.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/has)).

Regarding `array.reduce(and, true)` and `array.reduce(or, false)` specifically, you can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with the identity function as a callback, or `Boolean` for using a builtin.

Comment: I guess [`Math.imul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul) doesn't count.

Comment: I wouldn't call `Reflect.has` an operator.  I think of operators as being closed over a type, `:: a -> a -> a`.  But `has` is `:: Object -> String -> Bool`.  (Perhaps `String | Symbol`)

Comment: @ScottSauyet That's the [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) of *operator*, not the [programming language one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)). We do just fine with assignment operators (`Ref a -> a -> a`), control flow like `yield` (`a -> b`), unary typecasts like `+` (`Any -> number`) or the conditional operator `?` (`Bool -> a -> b -> a|b`). The `in` keyword definitely is an operator from its syntactical usage.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  I come from a background in math, so some programming concerns are obscured by old memories.  Thanks for the pointer. (Oh, wait! :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are only two methods for `&&` and `||`, by using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as callback.

For all other oerations, you need an own function.

```js
function checkAnd(array) {
    return array.every(Boolean);
}

function checkOr(array) {
    return array.some(Boolean);
}

console.log(checkAnd([true, true, true]));
console.log(checkAnd([true, false, true]));
console.log(checkAnd([false, false, false]));

console.log(checkOr([true, true, true]));
console.log(checkOr([true, false, true]));
console.log(checkOr([false, false, false]));
```

Comment: *"...or `Array#sort` with `Boolean` as callback."* `Array#some` would be rather more direct.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input. I'll give the thread some time to settle down, then pick the answer that drives the point most clearly home.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it was a typo, but the code was right.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the functions:

```js
function and(x, y) {
 return x && y;
}

function or(x, y) {
 return x || y;
}


bool_values = [true, true, false];
console.log("and", bool_values.reduce(and));
console.log("or", bool_values.reduce(or));

function add(x, y) {
 return x + y;
}

function multiply(x, y) {
 return x + y;
}

num_values = [1, 2.5, 3]
console.log("and", num_values.reduce(add));
console.log("or", num_values.reduce(multiply));
```